# Searching the Entity Framework domain model utilising Code First

Tags: entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, fluentvalidation

Got a very difficult EntityFramework Code First question. I'll keep this as simple as possible.

Imagine we have n number of classes, lets start with 2 for now

```
public class Person  
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}



public class Address   
{  
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }  
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }  
}
```

Now then, what I want to do is be able to search the domain model with a single string, i.e. something like DbContext.Search( "Foo" ). The call would search both the person and address tables for a string match and would return a list populated with both Person and Address entities.

Have to say I am not entirely clear how to go about it but I am considering using DataAnnotations to do something like this

```
public class Person  
{  
    **[Searchable]**  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}



public class Address   
{  
    **[Searchable]**  
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }  
    **[Searchable]**  
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }  
}
```

Am I on the right track?
Should I use the Fluent API instead?
Reflection?

Any and all thoughts massively appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "search the domain model"? Are you expecting searching already loaded entities or search in the database?

Comment: Ok, imagine I have the following classes all written and all exist in the db, Users, Addresses, People, Profiles etc. What I want to be able to do is perform a search across all searchable fields (marked by me) across all classes that contain a searchable field and return a union of all of the entities that contained the search term (in this case a simple string such as 'John Smith').

Answer (score 0):

the Find method searches only in the Primary Key column. If we don't make any column explicitly primary key column then find method will throw error. Generally EF convention takes propertyName+id as the primary key in the class. But if you want to search with Name then Make add [Key] to the property. it will become primary key and u will be able to find properties.
dbContext.Addresses.find("Foo");

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object type onto which you'll project 2 types of search results:

```
public class Result
{
    public string MainField { get; set; } 
    // you may have other properties in here.
}
```

Then find entities of each type that match your criteria, projecting them onto this type:

```
var personResults = DbContext.Persons
      .Where(p => p.Name == "Foo")
      .Select(p => new Result{MainField = p.Name}); 
      // don't forget to map to any other properties you have in Result as well


var addressResults = DbContext.Adresses
     .Where(a => 
        a.AddressLine1 == "Foo" ||  
        a.AddressLine2 == "Foo"
     ).
     .Select(a => new Result{MainField = a.AddressLine1 + ", " + a.AddressLine2 });
     // again, don't forget to map to any other properties in Result
```

Then merge the lists:

```
var allResults = personResults.Union(addressResults).ToList();
```

...at which point you can sort the list however you like.

"Result" and "MainField", are rather generic; just using them because I am not thoroughly aware of your domain model.

Comment: This is going in the right direction but it needs to be runtime discovered i.e. if I have 27 tables I cant write var table1 =, var table2 = etc. I need to be able to scan the domain model, discover which tables are searchable and then runtime create the queries. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Alan: Sounds like you are looking for full text search. That is not application for EF. The performance of this solution will be terrible.

Comment: So you don't have any knowledge of the DB schema ahead of time? I can't imaging how you'd do this with Entity Framework.

Comment: Yes, I kind of agree about full text searching but that's not what my client wants, I completely agree that the performance will / could be be a tad dodgy but if we are judicious about the fields we mark as searchable across the domain it may not prove too horrific. You could for example constrain the search to the Address table via an extension method on the DbContext but I really don't know where to start. How can I runtime traverse attributes (maybe via Fluent API) to analyse which fields are searchable and then push the containing entity type into a list for dynamic Linq generation.